# Check if collection contains a value

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, foreign-keys

I have the relationships set up (correctly i think).. I have 3 tables, users, comments, and comments' likes table.

In my blade, I can access `{{ $comment->commentLikes }}` with this and it's returning me:

```
[{"id":85,"comment_id":12,"user_id":1,"action":1},
{"id":86,"comment_id":12,"user_id":3,"action":1},
{"id":87,"comment_id":12,"user_id":4,"action":1},
{"id":88,"comment_id":12,"user_id":6,"action":1},
{"id":89,"comment_id":12,"user_id":9,"action":1}]
```

`user_id` represents owner of the like.

Now I want to check if this collection has the authenticated user, in other words if the current user liked this comment or not.. Is there a way to do that rather than using a for loop?  Maybe something like `{{ $comment->commentLikes->owner }}` so that I can use

'if (this) contains `Auth::user->id()`'...

Answer (score 0):

One way to check this is using `where()` and `first()` collection methods:

```
if ($comment->commentLikes->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// This works if $comment->commentLikes returns a collection
$userLikes = $comment->commentLikes->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->all();

if ($userLikes->count() > 0) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Using [Laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-search) you could do this:

```
$comment->commentLikes->search(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item->user_id == auth()->user()->id;
});
```

This will return `false` if none is found or index if the user is in the collection.

**Making it pretty**

But since you'll probably use this in a view I would package it in an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor), something like this:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function commentLikes() {
        // relationship defined
    }

    public function getHasLikedAttribute()
    {
        // use getRelationValue so it won't load again if it was loaded before
        $comments = $this->getRelationValue('commentLikes');

        $isOwner = $comment->commentLikes->search(function ($item, $key) {
            return $item->user_id == auth()->user()->id;
        });

        return $isOwner === false ? false : true;
    }
}
```

This way you can call `$comment->has_liked` which will return `true` if currently logged in user is in the relationship `commentLikes` or `false` if he isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if ($comment->commentLikes()->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->count() > 0)
```

This is **more efficient** than other answers posted because both the where() and the count() applies on the query builder object instead of the collection